# batch file to add hostname and IP to a string

Tags: batch-file

im looking for assistance or pointers for a small task i need to automate. I have a file containing hostnames and IP addresses in the following format:

```
HOSTNAME, IP ADDRESS
HOSTNAME, IP ADDRESS
```

I wish to take the contents of this file and create a new file which has the following contents:

```
new host [HOSTNAME] set address [IP ADDRESS]
```

With a new line for each host/ip in the original file. Can you please provide some pointers or suitable learning resources?

Comment: [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/), especially [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

Comment: This task is easily performed with the find and replace facility which forms part of most text editors.